# browsing (or downloading) R vignettes through ssh

Tags: linux, r, ssh, vignette

I am connected to my work computer (Linux Mint OS) through ssh. I am trying to use a package, but I need to read a documentation. Documentation is available via browseVignettes("package_name"). However since I am connected through the ssh, pdf file does not open. How can I download pdf to my local machine or read it through ssh? Package name is CODEX.

EDIT: I am on Mac OS

Comment: Are you using R on the command line, or RGui via X forwarding?

Comment: I am using R on the command line

Comment: I have also tried to login like this: 
MacBook-Pro:~ b$ ssh -C -X 11.11.111.111 -l l gnome-terminal
laba@11.11.111.111's password: 
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R uses the `browseUrl` function to open URLs in the browser. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/browseURL.html for more information.

You can change this option to your own function:

```
options(browser = function(url) {cat("R asked to open url: ", url, "\n")} )
```

Then either use [X forwarding](http://dyhr.com/2009/09/05/how-to-enable-x11-forwarding-with-ssh-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) to launch a browser on your remote machine (e.g. `firefox`) and display it on your local screen, or [use the SOCKS proxy](https://www.mikeash.com/ssh_socks.html) functionality of SSH to connect via your MacOS browser.